# Bind check box to an array item

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there anyway that I can bind a checkbox to an array item so I can then write out a loop statement that shows only those array items whose checkbox is checked?

Comment: Yes, there is. Try writing some code.

Comment: What do you want in the array? the id of each checkbox, the text of the checkbox, both? need more info

Comment: Oh my, an array that writes a loop that shows only array items that are checked? Sounds like you're looking for a DOM selector, but is having a little difficulty explaining what you want in "technical" terms.